# startActivityForResult(Intent,Requestcode) in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I believe we add the request code as a parameter as a way of identifying which child activity (started from the parent) is returning with the result.

But I assume (could be wrong ofc) that at any point in time, there will only be one activity available in the app...right ?.

Then why do we need this second parameter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use "startActivityForResult(Intent,Requestcode)" when I want to close many opened activities. example:

```
startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
```

when u call finish() it will close only the current activity and you will see the last opened activity
Lets say you opened activity A, from A you opened B then C, then D, let's say on internet connection error you have to close C and D and return to the activity B. u set the result :

```
setResult(100);
```

and in the activities that you want to close (example here C) you add:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode==100){
        setResult(100);
        finish();
    }
};
```

so on catch in the IOException you just have to set the result 100 and finish the activity

hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an Activity A. From it you call Activity B with **request code** b1. Or you call Activity C with a different request code c1. So when you return from B or C you know from which by the request code.

In B you do something and return to A. Sometimes you decided that what you did in B was a 'cancellation' and to mark it so you set **result code** to CANCEL. Other times you decide that what you did was a kind of 'pressing OK' and so you mark it with result code OK. Then back in A you do whatever you need to do based on those results.

You can call both Activities B and C with the same request code bu then you won't be able to distinguish from which you return to A.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [android developer basics](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html):

For- `public void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)`

> The integer argument is a "request code" that identifies your request.
>   When you receive the result Intent, the callback provides the same
>   request code so that your app can properly identify the result and
>   determine how to handle it.

And example-

You want to start the activity that can allow the user to pick the contact then use request code like:

```
static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;  // The request code
...
private void pickContact() {
    Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
    pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}
```

So when the called activity returns the result back to the caller activity, the caller activity will
identify the result by the request code it will receive from the called activity.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is the second only to verify if the new Activity finished succesfully or not. So you want to know, for example, if the login was succesfully in your second activity, you could pass an ERROR_CODE or SUCCESS_CODE. However, you don't like the second parameter use this method:

```
void startActivity(Intent intent)
```

Hope it helps.